# Create Input Field via Drop Down (select option) dynamic

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, input, field

i have a Select Option but I need you when clicking on an option, generate a new Input Field with the selected value and so it is removed from the Select Option, when you generate the Input Field beside this also generated a tag to remove this Input Field, when I remove this FIeld Input, the value returns to its Select Option.

More or less something like this (I'll explain with pictures):

[image: Here i select the value 1]

[image] and [image]

When on click in label Remove, its return at Select Option.

[image] and come back [image]

I was using the following link as an example:

[http://jsfiddle.net/jaredwilli/tZPg4/4/ CREATE INPUT FIELDS DYNAMIC](http://jsfiddle.net/jaredwilli/tZPg4/4/)

[http://jsfiddle.net/cqjJy/  CREATE INPUT FIELDS FROM SELECT OPTION](http://jsfiddle.net/cqjJy/)

```
    $(function () {
    var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
    var i = $('#p_scents p').size() + 1;

    $('#addScnt').live('click', function () {
        $('<p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i + '" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label> <a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
        i++;
        return false;
    });

    $('#remScnt').live('click', function () {
        if (i > 2) {
            $(this).parents('p').remove();
            i--;
        }
        return false;
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#claim").change(function () {
        $("#area").find(".field").remove();
        //or
        $('#area').remove('.field');
        if ($(this).val() == "Val1") {
            $("#area").append("<input class='field' type='text' />");

        }
    });

});
```

NOTE: This code is a example of the links.

Thanks I hope you can help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $("#claim").change(function () {
         $("#area").append("<div><input class='field' type='text' value='" + $(this).val() + "'/><label class='remove'>Remove</label></div>");
         $(this).find("option:selected").remove();
     });
     $("#area").on("click", ".remove", function () {
         var val = $(this).parent().find("input").val();         
         $("#claim").append("<option value='" + val + "'>" + val + "</option>");
         $(this).parent().remove();
     });
 });
```

[**Fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/cqjJy/36/)